# Are there any apps that copy files to another location whenever they change?

Tags: backup, sublimetext

I've been trying to change my IDE from NetBeans to [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

The most important thing that keeps me using NetBeans is the "Copy files from Sources Folder to another location" feature.

I can't find a plug-in for Sublime Text that can perform this task.

Comment: Note that Netbeans is not just an editor it does a build as well, which copies resources to the build directory so you need a build system as well e.g. gradle, ant and you set up copy tasks in that

Comment: It is polite to mark an answer as accepted. Although it is not polite to ask for it ;)

Comment: I was able to use `rsync`. Although, I'm not sure it answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved using 'Folder Actions'. You can create folder actions using AppleScript or Automator. If you do not know what 'Folder Actions are, you can read the [Folder Actions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html) page on the Apple site to get you started.

> **Folder Actions Reference**
>
> Folder Actions is a feature of OS X that lets you associate
>   AppleScript scripts with folders. A Folder Action script is executed
>   when the folder to which it is attached is opened or closed, moved or
>   resized, or has items added or removed. The script provides a handler
>   that matches the appropriate format for the action, as described in
>   this chapter.
>
> Folder Actions make it easy to create hot folders that respond to
>   external actions to trigger a workflow. For example, you can use a
>   Folder Action script to initiate automated processing of any photo
>   dropped in a targeted folder. A well written Folder Action script
>   leaves the hot folder empty. This avoids repeated application of the
>   action to the same files, and allows Folder Actions to perform more
>   efficiently.
>
> You can Control-click a folder to access some Folder Action features
>   with the contextual menu in the Finder. Or you can use the Folder
>   Actions Setup application, located in /Applications/AppleScript.

Note: you can create your own 'Folder Actions' using AppleScript Editor or Automator.